# What is image hot link prevention?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

Can anybody help me to find out what is the image hot link prevention that is configured in .htaccess file. Why is this important and what is their advantages if we use?

Comment: Please check my answer, it will help you to understand image hot link prevention feature.

Comment: have you even just tried to do a bit of research on this topic before asking? Btw this kind of question is clearly off topic on SO since it is primarly opinion based

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP? There is no PHP code here. In fact, there's no code at all. Who upvotes this?

Comment: @deepak - Can you please approve/accept my answer if that really helps us to understand the image hot link prevention? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a too broad question.

> Hotlink protection is preventing other sites from displaying your images.

This can save you lots of bandwidth.

Following **.htaccess** only allows referer from **yourdomain.com**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```